# Variable equal to text inside element

Tags: javascript

I wanna know if is possible to declare a variable and be equal to the text inside an element, for example:

```
<p id="demo">Hi</p>
```

And then, declare a variable named `demo = "Hi"`.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not very clear what your trying to do. Are you asking if you can assign the value of an element to variable?

Comment: exactly!!i want to declare a variable called demo and make it equal to "Hi"

Comment: Still not understanding just declare the variable like so const demo = 'Hi';

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to use `textContent` on the element instead as it doesn't force page reflow.

> **textContent** returns every element in the node.
>   In contrast, **innerText** is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements.
>   Moreover, since **innerText** takes CSS styles into account, reading the value of **innerText** triggers a ***reflow*** to ensure up-to-date computed styles.
>   (***Reflows*** can be computationally expensive, and thus should be avoided when possible.)

So you should do something around those lines:
`const demoText = document.getElementById("demo").textContent`
`const demoText = document.querySelector("#demo").textContent`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getElementById` as

```
var demo = document.getElementById("demo").innerText;
```

Note that you need add `script tag` before close `body` tag not in head tag.

```js
var demo = document.getElementById("demo").innerText;
console.log(demo)
```

```html
<p id="demo">Hi</p>
```

Comment: yes, but the value of the variable is not "Hi", is: <p id="demo">Hi</p>

Comment: did your script tag before </body> tag?

Comment: yes! and when I run console.log(demo), the result is:  <p id="demo">Hi</p>

Comment: did you use .innerText when getElementById?

Answer (score 1):

Just use document.getElementById or document.querySelector

```js
const demo = document.querySelector('#demo').innerText;

console.log(demo)
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hi</div>
```

Comment: yes, but the value of the variable is not "Hi", is: <p id="demo">Hi</p>

Answer (score 1):

try :

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const val = document.querySelector('#demo').innerText;
    console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Hi</div>
```